# Qué significa "efectivismo" en estudios de cine?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, identificación-de-término

Traduzco un [artículo](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=3020030) para portugués sobre la película [*Ama Lur*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExxIJlE_oUc) (1968), una película de 99 minutos. En ella se enfoca las terras bascas y la vida tradicional de la cultura de la región que corresponde al País Vasco. Hed que me viene el término "efectivismo" en un comentario hecho por un crítico de cine a la película (al cual ya no le gustaba la duración, le parecía muy larga la película):

> En otras secuencias [de la película *Ama Lur*] se advierte un empeño
> de jugar al **efectivismo** dinámico o plástico, com detrimento de la
> síntesis descriptiva. Aquí y allá sobreabundan los movimientos de
> cámara, se echa de ver que prevalecen algunas concepciones muy
> sugestivas, pero no tan prácticas, que están en la línea del
> documental grande, enfático, en su ambición formal. Y no se puede
> negar que ciertas consideraciones de índole concesiva afloran en
> diversas escenas de complacencia o de mero relleno.

Pienso que efectivismo tiene que ver con efectos especiales, pero en verdad, tampoco comprendo bien al cine, así si el efectivismo es dinámico o plástico, me va igual de sin sentido. En portugués, se dice "efeitos especiais" para los efectos especiales, pero no encuentro nada más técnico que eso para poner en lugar de efectivismo, ni términos, ni escuelas de cine, ni nada. Me imagino que efectivismo va empleado no a una tradición de cine, sinó a un perjuicio del crítico a una película que usa demasiado a los efectos especiales y que, desde su punto de vista, no debería hacerlo para que fuese una buena película. Sería este el sentido de "efectivismo" en el tramo?

Si necesitan más contexto, lo tienen en los capítulos 2.3 y 2.4 (donde se encuentra el tramo), acerca de la recepción y crítica a *Ama Lur*

Comment: Si buscas efectismo en WIkpedia https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?go=Ir&search=efectismo&title=Especial%3ABuscar&ns0=1&ns100=1&ns104=1 vas encontrar muchas referencias a otras peliculas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Efectivismo en el cine**

> En otras secuencias [de la película Ama Lur] se advierte un empeño de
> jugar al **ilusionismo** (con aspectos dinámicos o plásticos), con detrimento de la
> síntesis descriptiva.

---

> Em outras sequências [do filme Ama Lur] há um esforço para jogar o
> **ilusionismo** com aspectos dinâmicos ou plásticos, em detrimento da síntese descritiva.

---

En resumidas cuentas **el efectivismo**, es un término que se puede hallar hoy en día más allá de las artes, así lo encontramos en la política, en la moda... y siempre con la misma base de de crear una sensación, con distintos matices, en quien lo percibe.

Por tanto en el cine **el efectivismo** trataría de atraer la atención del espectador utilizando determinadas tácticas con el fin de hacer fácil lo que parece difícil. Así el **el efectivismo dinámico** sería por ejemplo el utilizado por la cámara, realizando "zoom", "barridos" u otras técnicas de movimiento, mientras que el **el efectivismo plástico** haría referencia a la utilización de esos mismos conocimientos que crean expectación o determinadas sensaciones en el espectador pero aplicados a los materiales, medios, esquemas de color, objetivos... El abuso de estas técnicas es tachado de sensacionalismo por algunos directores, sobre todo europeos, escuchándose frases como la de "menos efectismo y más cine" o simplemente aquellos que abiertamente dicen "estar contra el cine efectista", es decir, contra los métodos o procedimientos que abusan de esos recursos.

Desde mi punto de vista la palabra que andas buscando en la traducción y que se puede utilizar en la misma ya que creo que es fácilmente comprensible en ambos idiomas es la de "**ilusionismo**", pues que encaja perfectamente en el párrafo introductorio de la pregunta. De esta manera, **ilusionismo**, hace referencia al grado de "ilusión" que se consigue recreando los encuadres, con los movimientos realizados con la cámara, los esquemas de colores que aparecen, etc...

El **ilusionismo**, como el **el efectivismo** hacen fácil lo que aparentemente es y parece difícil y complejo, se trata de utilizar el ingenio y habilidades técnicas para construir una narrativa que a través de ellos el director en este caso consiga su objetivo, ya sea asombrar, conmover, emocionar o simplemente impactar en el espectador. De otro lado, el abuso de estas técnicas llevan a la crítica, reprobación y a una opinión negativa de la obra cinematográfica.

Comment: Gracias Diego, me sirvió muchísimo, una pena que no haya algo como "efectismo" en portugués, lo que me parece más intuitivo que decir "ilusionismo", ya que puede venir desasociado de una técnica de cine específica, pero se conoce al gimmick, aunque yo tampoco le encontré traducción. Una vez más, gracias por todo.

Answer (score 2):

### Efectismo

Claramente se refiere a **efectismo**:

> Efecto causado por un procedimiento o recurso empleado para impresionar fuertemente el ánimo.

<sub>*[RAE](https://dle.rae.es/efectismo)*</sub>

– En otras secuencias se advierte un empeño de jugar al efectivismo dinámico o plástico, com detrimento de la síntesis descriptiva.–

Dicho de otro modo:

- En otras secuencias se advierte un empeño de jugar al efectismo (utilizar recursos inmediatos y de fácil comprensión) dinámico (movimientos de cámara) o plásticos (distintos encuadres o enfoques), con detrimento de la síntesis descriptiva (para llamar la atención en lugar de favorecer una descripción del guión más práctica e inmediata).

Personalmente al efectismo le doy el valor de añadido superfluo, relleno. Tampoco es algo perteneciente exclusivamente al cine sino que se aplica a todas las artes. Una referencia contemporánea es Instagram, un océano de efectismos (o efectivismos).

La palabra correspondiente en inglés a *efectismo* es *gimmick* que tiene una definición más "estricta" y descriptiva:

> Something that is not serious or of real value that is used to attract people's attention or interest temporarily.

<sub>*[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gimmick)*</sub>

PD: no tiene nada que ver con efectos especiales, aunque un efecto especial puede ser ocasionalmente un efectismo.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me parece que se usa gimmick en portugués, según mis pesquisas rápidas, y no encontré precisamente una traducción. Tal vez aún estea por ser traducida al "efectismo", que parece claro en español que así lo es, pero no en portugués. Raro, no lo crees?